# How to animate a pulsating, folding sphere (or blob?) with geometry nodes?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I tried to recreate this animation with geometry nodes in Blender:
[Joe Ryba animation](https://twitter.com/joe_ryba/status/1580548778737573890)

I tried an icosphere with displacement and noise, wave and musgrave textures. The result is a displaced sphere but not something that seems to fold itself into it.
Could this be done with a plane? Looking forward to your ideas! :)

Comment: I would suggest a collection of 2 or more meatballs and keyframe some random movement

Comment: Meatballs... you know what I'm leaving it LOL.  Metaballs*

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the your reference, it is a deformation of a surface; UV's are preserved. So surface must not be created or destroyed.

This is a GN version.. I'm guessing the same could be done with *Displace* and *Subdivision* modifiers, but would be less easy to tweak.

The starting geometry, here,  is a UV-mapped 1st-level Icosphere, with one level of Catmull-Clark subdivision.

[image]

- The lo-res icosphere is displaced in and out along its normals by animated and mapped *Noise*, and then subdivided.
- The subdivided surface is then positively inflated along its own normals, clean.

The second phase can be repeated, for a more rounded effect.

To animate the noise, the lookup into the 3D noise is offset around an XY circle, once per animation period. (For a 100 frame loop, the 'Frame' input is multiplied by `2*pi/100`). Changing the Z of the circle will look up from different regions of the noise texture:

[image]

Changing the size of the circle ('Amplitude')  will scan the noise more or less quickly.

Adjusting those numbers, and the parameters of the *Noise* node, can make the animation a lot more gloopy, less staccato, than this example, which has had to be crunched down a bit for the 2MB gif:

[image]

Have a go and see if you get somewhere close:

[image]

Comment: Dear Robin, thank you so much for your detailed answer and your blend file! I learned a lot from your thinking and approach. Thanks again! :)